# What is this TypeScript pattern with interface and declare var?

Tags: typescript

Looking at [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3f638048781bbca3cbcb073bb43ee8c101b352cb/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts#L1196-L1222) as an example:

```
interface DOMPoint extends DOMPointReadOnly {
    w: number;
    x: number;
    y: number;
    z: number;
}

declare var DOMPoint: {
    prototype: DOMPoint;
    new(x?: number, y?: number, z?: number, w?: number): DOMPoint;
    fromPoint(other?: DOMPointInit): DOMPoint;
};

interface DOMPointReadOnly {
    readonly w: number;
    readonly x: number;
    readonly y: number;
    readonly z: number;
    matrixTransform(matrix?: DOMMatrixInit): DOMPoint;
    toJSON(): any;
}

declare var DOMPointReadOnly: {
    prototype: DOMPointReadOnly;
    new(x?: number, y?: number, z?: number, w?: number): DOMPointReadOnly;
    fromPoint(other?: DOMPointInit): DOMPointReadOnly;
};

interface DOMQuad {
    readonly p1: DOMPoint;
    readonly p2: DOMPoint;
    readonly p3: DOMPoint;
    readonly p4: DOMPoint;
    getBounds(): DOMRect;
    toJSON(): any;
}
```

Why are they declaring an uppercase variable the same name as the interface, with a different structure? What does it mean? And in the `DOMQuad` when they reference `DOMPoint`, are they referencing the `var` or the `interface`? What is the purpose of the var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's providing type information for the built-in `DOMPoint` class provided by the browser.

> Why are they declaring an uppercase variable the same name as the interface, with a different structure?

The interface defines what *instances* of `DOMPoint` look like. The `declare global var DOMPoint` tells TypeScript that a global exists (provided by the browser) that is a function that creates `DOMPoint` instances (`new`) and a `fromPoint` static method.

This mimics what TypeScript does with `class X { }`, where it both creates a type (`X`) for what *instances* of `X` will look like, and a constructor function (`X`) which is a runtime value (not just a type).

> And in the `DOMQuad` when they reference `DOMPoint`, are they referencing the var or the interface?

The interface.

> What is the purpose of the var?

Purely to tell TypeScript it exists. It doesn't *create* it (the browser does), it's just so TypeScript knows that using `DOMPoint` is valid, it's a global that exists with the given signature.

Answer (score 1):

Types and values can have identical names. They aren't necessarily connected.

```
type A = string
const A = 123

const test: A = A // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDOwBOBLAdgcwFAGMB7TFWBKARgCYBmXA404CFALjMTgHouoJVUhVEA)

---

One case where this comes into play often is classes.

```
class A {
  static fromX(x: number) {
    const instance = new A()
    instance.x = x
    return instance
  }
  x: number
}
```

In that snippet, an interface named `A` is implicitly created that defines the type of instances of the `A` class. But the value `A` is that of the class constructor, which has a totally different interface.

For instance:

```
const obj: A = { x: 123 } // fine
```

Here `obj` has all the properties that an instance of `A` would have, so it's the correct type and all is well. The static method `fromX` isn't on type `A` because it's not on the instances of `A`, it's on the constructor.

In fact, you can see the constructor has a very different type:

```
type AConstructor = typeof A
type fromXStaticMethod = AConstructor['fromX']
// type fromXStaticMethod = (x: number) => A
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1oQC5nQS2NAZgE4D2AtgBoAUAHgFzQB2ArqQEYCmhAlIiqtMGIMM0bMMwNg7aAF5G7AO5xKXPqjEYwk9gDpqs6NTXRC7dE0INR4rVL4BfPnUYsOhJI6ToAngAdpsADCQhiETMDoxIQGPv7E+HBeftJEZOQAypg4wACyZgAWxAAmBkEh6GERUQDaAOSpFLUAutAA9K3QsSkkFJlYuHnohSVyNPTMbJw8MgB8iUA)

So that's more or less what's being modeled here.

---

```
interface DOMPoint extends DOMPointReadOnly {
    w: number;
    x: number;
    y: number;
    z: number;
}

declare var DOMPoint: {
    prototype: DOMPoint;
    new(x?: number, y?: number, z?: number, w?: number): DOMPoint;
    fromPoint(other?: DOMPointInit): DOMPoint;
};
```

Here the interface `DOMPoint` is the type of instances, and the value `DOMPoint` is the constructor. So you can, for example, call `DOMPoint.fromPoint()` and get an instance of `DOMPoint` that has w,x,y,z properties.

---

```
interface DOMQuad {
    readonly p1: DOMPoint;
    readonly p2: DOMPoint;
    readonly p3: DOMPoint;
    readonly p4: DOMPoint;
    getBounds(): DOMRect;
    toJSON(): any;
}
```

Here a `DOMQuad` instance has four points, and each point is a prop that is a `DOMPoint` instance.